# Post Back input field that is not part of model

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a form that uses a `List<SomeClass>` to **bind** and **post** back multiple values.
My form binds fine to the list and returns updated values.

Additionally. I need to **post** back the value of a `TextBox` that is on the form. When the form posts, `ViewData["Message"]` is null. I cannot find the error.

See my code below:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(e => ViewData["Message"], 2, 70, new { @class = "form-control", 
@id="Message"})
```

How do I get a `TextBox` to **pass back its actual value** through `ViewBag` or `ViewData`?